# how to add list items in table view in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am trying to add items to a table view. I can see that everytime I click on the button a new row inserts into the table, but the cell is empty. When I debug the code I can see all the items in the list but I cannot see them displayed on the app itself. The items "1", "2" and "3" are not displayed as well

```
@IBOutlet weak var itemLbl: UITextField!
    var items: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)


    }

func insertItem(){
    items.append(itemLbl.text!)

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: items.count - 1,section: 0 )
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    itemLbl.text = ""
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

So the insert does work, but I just cannot display the text in the table. I do get a new cell for every item that I add, but its just white empty space, instead of the value that I just added

EDIT:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let itemLbl  =  items[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell") as! ItemCell

        cell.itemLbl.text = itemLbl
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Have you already implemented the UITableViewDataSource methods?

Comment: what is the code for `cellForRowAt`function?

Comment: YEs I have and the only thing that it does is "return items.count"

Comment: Can you try this?
 self.tblView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: self.yourArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)

Comment: @AndresGomez See edit!!

Comment: @HarishPrabakaran where should I add it?

Comment: tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic) instead of this try
 tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: items.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)

Comment: Or simply do the below


           items.append(itemLbl.text!)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

Comment: @HarishPrabakaran I can see that my tree in the storyboard looks like this: Table view --> Item cell --> Content view --> item label. I can see that everything that I add to the list is added to the item label and not the Item cell.. Could that be the issue?

Comment: It would do you a great deal of good if you could post the rest of your dataSource methods.

Answer (score 3):

It's best to reload the table whenever your data source changes, which you can do like this:

```
var items: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"] {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func insertItem(){
    if let text = itemLbl.text { 
        items.append(itemLbl.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just be sure that tableView already exists when setting items for the first time.

Comment: The didSet block does not get called the first time (at initialization), so it's actually no different than calling tableView.reloadData() from inside the insertItem() method in that respect. This way just has the advantage of also reloading the table if, for example, data is removed from the array.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple possibilities that could cause this issue. The first thing you should check is that in your list, make sure you are using a reuse identifier for the cell prototype and that you are referencing it. Additionally, make sure you reload the table whenever you add an element (don't constantly do it as it will drain the user's battery). If neither of these are working, it's possible you didn't connect your outlets properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `tableView.reloadData()` ? Also, do not force unwrap `itemLabel.text`.

```
func insertItem(){
    if let itemText = itemLabel.text {
       items.append(itemText)

       tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Make sure to also add `tableView.reloadData()` at the end of `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: what would itemText be in this case?

Comment: Sorry, should be let itemText. Fixed in answer.